# Fuel UX wizard component not displaying correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wizard, fuelux

I'm trying to use the fuel ux wizard component as shown in the example:

http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#wizard

but it does not display correctly.

My code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/fuelux.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/fuelux/require.js"></script>
<script src="js/fuelux/all.js"></script>
</head> 

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="workflowWizard" class="wizard">
        <ul class="steps">
        <li data-target="#step1" class="active"><span class="badge badge-info">1</span>Step 1<span class="chevron"></span></li>
        <li data-target="#step2"><span class="badge">2</span>Step 2<span class="chevron"></span></li>
        <li data-target="#step3"><span class="badge">3</span>Step 3<span class="chevron"></span></li>
        <li data-target="#step4"><span class="badge">4</span>Step 4<span class="chevron"></span></li>
        <li data-target="#step5"><span class="badge">5</span>Step 5<span class="chevron"></span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="actions">
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-prev"> <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>Prev</button>
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-next" data-last="Finish">Next<i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="step-content">
        <div class="step-pane active" id="step1">This is step 1</div>
        <div class="step-pane" id="step2">This is step 2</div>
        <div class="step-pane" id="step3">This is step 3</div>
        <div class="step-pane" id="step4">This is step 4</div>
        <div class="step-pane" id="step5">This is step 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any ideas on what i'm missing?

Answer (score 17):

Okay I found the problem.

The tag

```
<html lang="en">
```

needs to include the fuelux class:

```
<html lang="en" class="fuelux">
```

Comment: Not necessarily the whole <html> tag. The `fuelux` class is needed in the parent of the fuelux components (due to the CSS selectors used in the framework).

Answer (score 0):

If using php preprocessing, add this line at the beginning of the CSS file:

```
<?php header('content-type: text/css'); ?>
```

[Lighttpd and phph]